# Is it a fashion to omit “is” as in “this a problem that can seem unanswerable.”?

Tags: phrase-requests, omissibility

I often see cases that a verb and a preposition are omitted as I posted a question the other day about the omission of “in” in the line, “Perry has had difficulty planting doubt about Romney.”

Today I saw the case “*is*” is omitted as “*this a problem*” in the following sentence of aNew York Times article written by Michael P. Lynch under the title, “Reason for Reason."

> “Disagreements like this (Evolutionism and Creationism) give rise to an unnerving question: How do we rationally defend our most fundamental epistemic principles? Like many of the best philosophical mysteries, *this a problem* that can seem both unanswerable and yet extremely important to solve.”

I think it should be “this is a problem.” But if it is the case, can we use “*a*,” not “*the*” when “the problem” is modified (or defined) by “that clause”? (though I feel like an article maniac these days.)

Is the omission of “*is*” today’s fashion, or just a typo?

You may say the author isn’t NYT’s writer unworthy for digging in each phrasing. But according to opinionator @nytimes.com, Michael Lynch is a contemporary philosopher, who must be the master of logic and rhetoric.

Comment: I'm tempted to say it's just a typo.

Comment: "Is this a fashion?"  In English, no.  In Russian, yes.

Comment: Being a master of rhetoric may mean you know how to turn a phrase to your advantage (note the rhetorical trick), but it doesn't necessarily mean you can communicate clearly. Being a master of logic may actually harm your undwerstanding of English, which is not the most logical of subjects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a typo rather than on actual English usage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That usage is just not acceptable. There's no way that was intentional -- it's clearly a  typo.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a typo to me. I don't recognize the sentence as grammatical. When you leave out the specifics, the sentence seems to be missing an 'is'.

> Like X, this [is] a problem that can seem Y and Z.

Without the 'is' there, the sentence has no main verb.